# How to test if a user inputted string is in a list?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, list

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a script that gets a users choice to open a program like Windows Command Prompt. Since Windows Command Prompt is also opened with 'cmd' I want the user to have the ability to type both and get the same result.

I know I can put it in multiple elif statements, but I was wondering if I can just put the two (or more) in a list and have python check if what the user input is in the list, and if it is, open the program or does whatever else

here is some test code I have been working on for a bit and am completely stumped at this point:

```
userInput = input(">")

userList = []
userList.append(userInput)

commandPrompt = ["cmd", "command prompt"]
testList = ["test1", "test2"]

if userList in commandPrompt:
    print("cmd worked")
elif userInput == testList:
    print("testList worked")
else:
    print("Did not work")

print(userList)
```

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I checked all over Google and Stack Overflow and was not able to find any article quite like what I was wanting to do or explain if it is or is not possible.

Comment: I am not able to understand clearly what you want to achieve, would you mind adding an example with an input and its respective output?

Comment: Using the `input()` function has nothing to do with Windows command-prompt and `cmd` shell—so your question makes little sense as it now stand. Please [edit] it and try to clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, you're checking if `userList` is in `commandPrompt`. But `commandPrompt` never contains a list so this won't ever be satisfied.

`if userInput in commandPrompt:` feels like it might be what you need. You don't need to put the user's input into a list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Doe! I knew I was missing one tiny detail in that particular area, I just could not figure out what. My code is working exactly as I have been wanting it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your code to this:

```
userInput = input(">")

commandPrompt = ["cmd", "command prompt"]
testList = ["test1", "test2"]

if userInput in commandPrompt:
    print("cmd worked")
elif userInput in testList:
    print("testList worked")
else:
    print("Did not work")
```

This will work just the way you want. You don't actually need the `userList` for anything.